# Using a QListView or similar effectively in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt4

I am slowly getting used to using the Qt4 GUI framework. In a project I am working on, I need to be able to add/edit/remove `Team` objects in a list. Coming from a C#.NET perspective, I would do something like

```
List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();
teamsListBox.DataSource = teams;
teamsListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Then use buttons on the form to do the adding/removing/editing.

But, from what I can tell, there is no easy way to do this in Qt. I have looked over the documentation for QListView, QListWidget, QStandardItemModel, etc. but I cannot figure out how to get the equivalent Qt code for the C#.

My objective is to show the `Team`s in a list box of some kind, then be able to add/remove/edit the `Team`s underneath it at runtime.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qabstractitemmodel.html) and [`QStandardItemModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qstandarditemmodel.html) or create a customized TeamItemModel class for your teams that inherits from QAbstractItemModel. Those customized class will manage how the items are displayed in the Widget like QListView.

A simple for `QString` item  example with [`QStringList`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qstringlist.html):

```
QStringList list;
list << "item1" << "item2" << "item3" << "item4" << "item5";
ui->listView->setModel(new QStringListModel(list));
```

Then adding/removing/updating a `Team` should be easier than what you have tried.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there an easier way that avoids subclassing? Like creating a model from a `QList<Team>`?

Comment: There are DirModel, ProxyModel and StandardItemModel but no list model. I think You have to subclass QAbstractItemModel for your need.

Comment: Patrice, can you give a sample code with QStandardItemModel containing more than 1 column and few rows for QListView ?

Comment: Have you seen the sample in the Trolltech doc?  http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qstandarditemmodel.html#details